# How to send email from a CQ5 form

Tags: email, aem

I have got a requirement which has 2 parts:

1. The form content will be saved into a jcr node.
2. The form content will be sent out to a specific email address.

I have used CQ5 foundation form component in order to implement part 1. In there, I specified the form action type as 'Store Content' and the form content path which is storing the form content right at the location. However, I am facing an issue with part 2. I created a emailServlet class which handles the generic email implementation specific to my project. This class resides in the project's bundle. Now my question is, how  I can implement the part 2 using the CQ5 form action (type = Mail) to forward it to my email Servlet class.

Please let me know how to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I can't give you real specific details and code examples, but I can at least shed light how to get Adobe CQ5 to send form data in an email and store it to the DAM at the same time.

In our case, we had CQ5 store form data for each configured form component in the DAM (repository) by default by setting the form action in the component to Store Content.

In order to get it to also send the form data via email, you will need to create a custom email sending process and use a Workflow to pass the form data to that process.  The workflow will be added to the Form tab of the form edit window.

Form handler workflow:
[image]

Attaching workflow to the form component:
[image]

In our case, the workflow consists of nothing more than specifying the SendEmail process that we wrote and the email template path for the message we wish to use as an argument, as you can see in the first image.  Sorry I can't share the actual code with you - I'm not allowed.

I hope that helps.